# How to select last order date for each customer in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

```
table_customers(customer_id, customer_name)
table_orders(customer_id, order_id, order_datetime)
```

I want to get `last order date` for each `customer`. If customer has not placed any order return `00-00-0000` for her.

This is my query.

```
select C.customer_id , date(O.order_datetime) 
from table_customers C 
INNER JOIN table_orders O ON C.customer_id = O.customer_id 
group by O.customer_id order by O.order_datetime desc limit 1;
```

It is returning last order date for for last customer only.

How to get last order date for all the customers?

Comment: Remove the `limit 1`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi checkout my sql below..

```
select coalesce(max(o.order_datetime), '0000-00-00 00:00:00') as last_order_date, c.customer_id 
from table_orders as o
right join table_customers as c on o.customer_id = c.customer_id
group by c.customer_id
order by c.customer_id;
```

This might help you.

The sample results are given below.

[image]

Comment: it's my pleasure.. :D

Comment: I have one more query, on similar line. i have posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982167/how-to-select-customers-final-balance-for-all-customer-in-mysql Please check if you can help me on that?

Answer (score 0):

You can do as below

```
SELECT customer_table.*, orders.order_date FROM customer_table left join (SELECT customer_id, order_date FROM (SELECT tmp.* from  order_table ORDER BY order_date DESC ) as tmp GROUP BY tmp.customer_id) as orders on orders.customer_id= customer_table.id where order.order_date NOT NULL
```