# How to select customer's final balance for all customer in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables.

```
table_customers - customer_id, name
table_orders - order_id, customer_id, order_datetime
table_wallet - customer_id, amount, type  // type 1- credit, type 2- debit
```

I need to get all customers, their total balance, and their last order date and order id. This is my query.

```
SELECT 
C.customer_id, 
C.name, 
COALESCE( SUM(CASE WHEN type = 2 THEN -W.amount ELSE W.amount END), 0) AS value,
COALESCE( max( O.order_id  ) , '0' ) AS last_order_id, 
COALESCE( max( date( O.order_datetime ) ) , '0000-00-00' ) AS last_order_date
FROM 
table_customers as C 
LEFT JOIN 
table_wallet as W 
ON C.customer_id = W.customer_id 
LEFT JOIN
table_orders AS O
ON W.customer_id = O.customer_id
group by C.customer_id
ORDER BY C.customer_id
```

Everything is coming correct except customer's total value. From result it seems its getting added multiple times.

What is wrong in query? Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: where is total balance? do you mean value? could you make the schema and records in http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ ? Then, I can help you better

Comment: yes, its value. i have updated the question.

Comment: Make a fiddle please. It's not easy to help without sample data

Comment: @Mojtaba i have build the schema. Please find it on http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1957d3/1 Value for first record need to be 20, but its coming out 60.

Comment: in this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/560f2/1 its not showing last order date for customer#3

Comment: @Strawberry What's Brilliant in that? It was just a typo mistake. Can you help on what's wrong on query?

Answer (score 1):

This is doing a many-to-many join on `table_customers` to `table_orders`, which will mess with your sums. Rather do this:

```
SELECT C.customer_id
, C.name
, IFNULL((SELECT SUM(IF(W.type=2, -1*W.amount, W.amount))
    FROM table_wallet W 
    WHERE C.customer_id = W.customer_id),0) AS value
, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(DATE(O.order_id))
    FROM table_orders O 
    WHERE C.customer_id = O.customer_id),'0') AS last_order_id
, IFNULL((SELECT MAX(DATE(O.order_datetime))
    FROM table_orders O 
    WHERE C.customer_id = O.customer_id),'0000-00-00') AS last_order_date
FROM table_customers as C 
ORDER BY C.customer_id
```

This will return one row per customer, then subquery the fields you want. I've substituted `IFNULL` for `COALESCE` as I find it cleaner, but this is a preference thing.

Comment: Thanks for response. But Its giving error unknown column W.customer_id in Where clause in this condition "WHERE C.customer_id = W.customer_id"

Comment: Created a fiddle. please check  sqlfiddle.com/#!9/560f2/1

Comment: Oh derp, I just copy + pasted from one subquery and forgot to change the aliases